# switch and/or iff function in SSRS. How to use both or any for two given columns

Tags: ssrs-2012

How to use =SWITCH & IIF condition to change color in SSRS if the condition is met. I have two columns “ScheduledDate” (which is date/time), and Activity(which is text format). I want to change the color of Activity (which has the output as Complete, Current, Overdue), if the ScheduledDate is greater than today’s date, then I want to change the Overdue data in Column Activity to RED.

Should using Switch would be good or IIF. How? Can anyone please give an example?

Appreciate any help on this one.

Thanks,
Niki

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, if you only need set RED without setting multiple color for fields, it's better to use IIF(). Base on your condition, try the expression below:

=IIF(Fields!ScheduleDate.Value>Now() and Fields!Activity.Value="Overdue",Red,Black)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It works. Thanks for your help.

=iif(Fields!ScheduleDate.Value > Now() and Fields!Activity.Value ="Cancelled","Red",
 iif(Fields!ScheduleDate.Value < Now() and Fields!Activity.Value ="Created","Green","Red"))